Is there any way to get only column names where we have modified values in CDC table?
DECLARE @ColumnName NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @SQLQuery NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';
DECLARE @HasColumns BIT = 0;

DECLARE ColumnCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'dbo_OINV_CT' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'cdc'; -- Adjust the schema name if necessary

OPEN ColumnCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM ColumnCursor INTO @ColumnName;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF @HasColumns = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE 1=0 ';
        SET @HasColumns = 1;
    END

    SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery +
        'OR EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM cdc.dbo_OINV_CT t1
            INNER JOIN cdc.dbo_OINV_CT t2 ON t1.__$start_lsn = t2.__$start_lsn AND t1.__$seqval = t2.__$seqval
            WHERE t1.[__$operation] = 3 -- Before update
            AND t2.[__$operation] = 4 -- After update
            AND t1.' + QUOTENAME(@ColumnName) + ' <> t2.' + QUOTENAME(@ColumnName) + '
        )' + CHAR(13);

    FETCH NEXT FROM ColumnCursor INTO @ColumnName;
END

CLOSE ColumnCursor;
DEALLOCATE ColumnCursor;



-- Execute the constructed SQL query if columns are found
IF @HasColumns = 1
BEGIN
    SET @SQLQuery = REPLACE(@SQLQuery, 'OR EXISTS', 'AND (EXISTS');
    SET @SQLQuery = REPLACE(@SQLQuery, ' OR)', ')');
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'No columns found in dbo_OINV_CT.';
END

Trying to get only column names where we modified values from CDC table, script is not completely executed.

Msg 191, Level 15, State 1, Line 1712
Some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply. Rewrite the query or break it up into smaller queries.


What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want the list of columns in the CDC table? Use select * from cdc.captured_columns Or do you want the columns that were updated for a given __$update_mask from the CDC table? Use sys.fn_cdc_is_bit_set function. Or do you just want to know all columns that have ever been changed in any row in the CDC table? What do you want for insert or deletes?

Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results.

This sounds like X & Y problem, let's say you have changed 5 rows, with various columns changed between each row, what kind of result are you looking for? And most importantly, what for?

If you want to find out if there were any UPDATE rows anywhere in the CDC table which show a modification on each column, then you can aggregate all the update masks by bit.
SELECT
  cc.column_name
FROM cdc.captured_columns cc
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM cdc.dbo_OINV_CT t
    WHERE sys.fn_cdc_is_bit_set(cc.column_ordinal, t.__$update_mask) = 1
      AND t.__$operation = 4
)
WHERE cc.object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.OINV_CT');


Thanks CharlieFace to assist me, when I tried use the same script then got error messages: 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
The data types varbinary and varbinary are incompatible in the '&' operator. I even tried to cast the values in varbinary but seems I am not able to understand the developed query by you as looks like its a very high level for me as first time I used the CDC concepts and columns so please assist me to execute it successfully to get the column name which is having updated values in it

Thanks for your response, query executed without any flaw but not returned any column name.

Let me share what I have in CDC.dbo_OINV_CT table , please let me know how can share those 6-7 records with you so that you can have a proper check, it would be best way if you would having rows on front of you but dont know how can I attach here or may be copy in correct format

When I tried to use suggested right or left to trim then again getting incapability error :Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
The data types varbinary and varchar are incompatible in the '&' operator.

I am not sure but still not able to see the column names, should I make some new changes in column before have the execution of the script. additionally, would you mind to share about the use of udate mask as not able to understand how we can track the amended values in a column through this. just curious to know... and not sure how I can achieve the asked as still not able to get column names where amended the values

Would be waiting to get my solution :)

OK I've substantially changed the query. It may be a bit less efficient though, but at least it will definitely work. This will tell you if there was ever an UPDATE which included a particular column.

Thanks for reply, as I am still confuse about hexadecimal values but I just have simple snippet execution why I am not getting column name and checked  this snippet

Appreciate you time and help, new code is working SELECT
cc.column_name
FROM cdc.captured_columns cc
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
FROM cdc.dbo_OINV_CT t
WHERE sys.fn_cdc_is_bit_set(cc.column_ordinal, t.$update_mask) = 1
AND t.$operation = 4
) till here only...... Thanks Thanks a Ton

But when I Adding and cc.object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.OINV') in the script then its returning blank dont know why it is

Seems you are adding a extra where clause in the script however I have replace with and but still the last condition is stopping the result and if without last condition I executed the script is returning the correct column name,

Thanks a lot to support, Its working perfectly ... I was missing the schema name in the table when wrote the last condition

I was thinking how we can fetch old and new values as well with the column name as we dont have any relationship between both the tables, do you know any other way to get all the information like an audit table, modifed column names, old values, new values, user name, date time, system IP etc if we can implemet in the same query SELECT
cc.column_name
FROM cdc.captured_columns cc
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
FROM cdc.dbo_OINV_CT t
WHERE sys.fn_cdc_is_bit_set(cc.column_ordinal, t.$update_mask) = 1
AND t.$operation = 4
)
and cc.object_id = OBJECT_ID('CDC.DBO_OINV_CT');

That's an entirely different question, that's what the CDC functions are for. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/cdc-fn-cdc-get-all-changes-capture-instance-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16
